# How would I add a user registration detail to wp_users?

Tags: wordpress

Here is my predicament right now, I currently run a Minecraft Server as alot of people in my community like to play it. The way I currently have it set up, users who sign up on the website have access to the Minecraft server. Minecraft connects to the database and checks to see if they have registered or if their name is there at all. But the problem with this is that users have to sign up with their Minecraft username, some user;s do not like to do that. Right now I would just like a column in wp_users to display a customizable text field saying Minecraft username. 
Sorry if this is a duplicate at all. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new column in the wp_users table which I would advise against, you can use user metadata. You can [update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) and [get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) usermeta.

If you are wanting to code this yourself I think you will need to create your own signup form and the accompanying PHP file to handle it as I don't think there are the correct hooks to get everything you need, although I could be wrong. I'm happy to run you through this if required.

Otherwise, you could try some plugins, although I've not done this. Perhaps [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta/) or [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta-manager/) - Note I've not tried either of these and not 100% sure they will do what you are after.

To save and show user meta fields on the users profile, try this in your functions.php file;

```
<?php
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_user_meta_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_user_meta_fields' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'update_user_meta_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'update_user_meta_fields' );

function update_user_meta_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mincraftUser', $_POST['mincraftUser'] );
}

function add_user_meta_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3>Extra Custom Meta Fields</h3>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="mincraftUser">Twitter User Name</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="mincraftUser" name="mincraftUser" size="20" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'mincraftUser', $user->ID )); ?>">
            <span class="description">Please enter your Twitter Account User name, eg: oneTarek</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php }
```

Comment: How would I get it to show the field on the registration page?

Comment: I've used User Meta before but can't seem to get the minecraft name to actually show on peoples profiles so they can change it

Comment: Have updated my answer to show how to show user meta on the their profile.

Comment: Iv'e tried and from what I see it will not save the info that the user types, I tried my own code and this and got the same result

Comment: This code works, so something else must be going on. You you've put this code in your functions.php file? What happens when you go to your profile, do you see the field show up?

Comment: Yes in the users dashboard the field shows up but it still will not save the field as its own key

Comment: What do you mean by this: "but it still will not save the field as its own key". How are you trying to get this meta data?

Comment: When you specify new usermeta fields it's placed as a metakey

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to say. Now that you have the minecraft username stored, what problem are you running into now?

Comment: The problem is that it's not storing at all, when you enter a name it doesnt save at all

Comment: So you enter a name into the field, hit update profile, and then the page reloads and the value is not there any more?

Comment: Yes, and it's not in the usermeta table when I check with phpmyadmin

Comment: Ah okay I understand. Well I can confirm this is the correct code, as I've used it many times and have double checked and am running a local version of WP with this coding working. 

My guess is its either your theme or existing plugins breaking this functionality. Can you switch to twentytwelve theme, and turn off all plugins and just confirm that this code will work.

Comment: Could you please add me on skype to prevent too many comments skype:khailzxsniper